# Add custom routes to devise returns 404 ActionNotFound

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, rails-routing, devise-token-auth

I would like to create a new routes and method inside my Sessions Controller within Devise. I am using [devise_token_auth](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth)

Here is my original `routes.rb` for devise :

```
namespace :api do
    namespace :v1 do
      mount_devise_token_auth_for 'User', as: 'user', at: 'auth', controllers: {
        token_validations:  'api/v1/users/token_validations',
        confirmations:      'api/v1/users/confirmations',
        registrations:      'api/v1/users/registrations',
        passwords:          'api/v1/users/passwords',
        sessions:           'api/v1/users/sessions'
      }
    end
end
```

which give me these classic routes :

```
new_api_v1_user_session GET          /api/v1/auth/sign_in(.:format)                   api/v1/users/sessions#new
api_v1_user_session POST             /api/v1/auth/sign_in(.:format)                   api/v1/users/sessions#create
destroy_api_v1_user_session DELETE   /api/v1/auth/sign_out(.:format)                  api/v1/users/sessions#destroy
new_api_v1_user_password GET         /api/v1/auth/password/new(.:format)              api/v1/users/passwords#new
edit_api_v1_user_password GET        /api/v1/auth/password/edit(.:format)             api/v1/users/passwords#edit
....
```

I have also inside my directory tree :

```
controllers
-- api
--- v1
----users
----- confirmations_controller.rb
----- passwords_controller.rb
----- registrations_controller.rb
----- sessions_controller.rb
```

Now I want to create a new custom method and routes inside the sessions controller for connected people. I want this new route : `/api/v1/auth/token`

So here is what I add to my routes :

```
devise_scope :user do   
    post '/auth/tokens', to: 'users/sessions#tokens'
end
```

And the result when I do `rails routes`, which looks fine :

```
api_v1_auth_tokens POST   /api/v1/auth/tokens(.:format)                    api/v1/users/sessions#tokens
```

But in Postman when I call `POST {url}/api/v1/auth/tokens` I get the classic 404 error **AbstractController::ActionNotFound**.

> [Devise] Could not find devise mapping for path
> "/api/v1/auth/tokens". This may happen for two reasons:
>
> 1. You forgot to wrap your route inside the scope block. For example:
>
> devise_scope :user do
> get "/some/route" => "some_devise_controller"   end
>
> 2. You are testing a Devise controller bypassing the router.    If so,
>    you can explicitly tell Devise which mapping to use:
>
>    @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
>
> Completed 404 Not Found in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations:
> 110)

But I am doing what the hint is telling me. What am I missing ?

Comment: does changing `post '/auth/tokens'` to `post '/auth/fcm_tokens'`, solves your issue?

Comment: You made no mention about the action itself, so I found worth asking: have you `def tokens ... end` in your `sessions_controller`?

Comment: Yes yes obviously but thanks for asking, for now this is just a method with `puts` inside to test that the route is working so I didn't copy/paste it here

Comment: Does changing `post '/auth/tokens', to: 'users/sessions#tokens'` in the `devise_scope` to `post '/auth/tokens', to: 'api/v1/users/sessions#tokens'` change anything?

Comment: No because the Controller#Action generated becomes : `api/v1/api/v1/users/sessions#tokens`